# Accessing applications using python

Tags: keyboard, asus

So I want to write a code that can change my keyboard's backlit color according to the time of the day

I have an asus rog strix laptop and want python to use ROG aura core(application which can configure the keyboard's backlit color) to change my keyboard's color. The problem I have run into is that I don't know where the application is located and how to allow my code to make changes in it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible for you to change the backlight settings of your keyboard using code... ASUS ROG Aura Core application is a propriety solution and hence, you can't access its code base to make desired changes...

The only way that this might be possible is if the devs at ASUS have released an API that allows you to modify the settings...

After searching the Internet, I did find that ASUS has recently released an Aura SDK that might do the trick... But, after reading the documentation and looking at some repositories at GitHub, I believe that this SDK is built for PC custom builders... And, I believe that you will need to use either C++/C# to code in it...

So, Python is of no use here...

Click the link to visit the [Asus Aura SDK Official Site](https://www.asus.com/campaign/aura/us/SDK.html)

Tip: You have used the wrong tag in this question... The ideal tag to be used here should have been 'Asus', 'aura-core'...

Comment: Hey I am very consistent in c/c++. Thanks for the answer. Really helped :)